# How to getResource from jar with compiled groovy classes?

Tags: groovy, jar, classloader, getresource

I have the groovy script. I compiled it with groovyc and jar'ed classes. So script1.class is in jar's root. And I put some file foo.bar in jas's root too.
How do I get that file with getResource? Which ClassLoader should I use? And how do I get this ClassLoader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a groovy class which exists in the same package where the resource is placed.

```
def path = 'foo.txt'
def inputStream = Script1.class.getResourceAsStream(path)
```

The sample code above,  allows you to access the file named `foo.txt` which is placed in the same package in which `Script.class` exists. You need to manipulate the stream as per your need.

Comment: `def inputStream = Script1.class.getResourceAsStream( path )` should work as well